# Calculus by Spivak, Excercise 13-7

Tags: calculus

I am currently working with the textbook "Calculus" by Michael Spivak. Specifically i tried excercise 13-7. I came up with a different solution than the author. The Solutions Manual only gives the scetch of a proof and frankly, i don't understand it in whole. But i think, my solution uses a similar idea. So, i present my solution here. Can anyone tell me, if it is written correctly and give possibilities of improvement? Thanks in advance.

For the following proof we assume two functions $f$ and $g$ defined and integrable on the interval $[a, b]$ and a partition $P= \{t_0,...,t_n\}$ of $[a, b]$. It is one step of a longer proof for the existence of the integral for the sum of two functions and it relates to the least upper bounds of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in an interval $[t_{i-1}, t_i]$ of the partition. We define these least upper bounds as follows:

$$m_i'=inf\{f(x):t_{i-1} \le x \le t_i\}$$
$$m_i''=inf\{g(x):t_{i-1} \le x \le t_i\}$$
$$m_i=inf\{(f+g)(x):t_{i-1} \le x \le t_i\}$$

**Proposition**: With the above mentioned assumptions and definitions, the following inequality is true:

$$m_i \ge m_i' + m_i''$$

**Proof**: In an arbitrary interval $[t_{i-1}, t_i]$ we have $m_i$, $m_i'$ and $m_i''$. Since $f$ and $g$ are integrable and thus bounded on $[a,b]$, these occur at certain $x'$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ with $(f+g)(x')=m_i$, $(f)(x_1)=m_i'$ and $(g)(x_2)=m_i''$.

Here $x'$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ can be equal or distinct. First, we assume that $x'=x_1 \neq x_2$.

We can write

$$m_i' + m_i'' = inf \{f(x_1)+g(x_2):t_{i1} \le x_1, x_2 \le t_i \}$$

Now, since $g(x_2)=inf\{g(x):t_{i-1} \le x \le t_i\} \le g(x')$ we have

$$m_i=(f+g)(x')=f(x')+g(x')=f(x_1)+g(x') \ge f(x_1)+g(x_2)=m_i'+m_i''$$

Similarly we can deduce the same result for $x'=x_2 \neq x_1$ and $x' \neq x_1 \neq x_2$.

If $x'=x_1=x_2$ we have

$$m_i=(f+g)(x')=f(x')+g(x')=f(x_1)+g(x_2)=m_i'+m_i''$$

In either case we have

$$m_i \ge m_i' + m_i''$$

So our proof is complete. $\blacksquare$

Comment: fyi, this doesn't require integrability.  The components of the set that $m_i$ are being drawn from are the other two,  so each element of the other two sets are bounded below by their infinum,  so the sum is bounded by the sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not justified to say that $x'$, $x_1$, and $x_2$ must exist with $f(x_1) = m_i'$ etc. Knowing $f$ is continuous would be one condition guaranteeing that, but an integrable function does not need to be continuous.

A counter-example function, defined on $0 \leq x \leq 1$:

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
2^{\lfloor \log_2 x \rfloor} & x > 0 \\
1 & x = 0
\end{cases} $$

$\inf\{f(x) : 0 \leq x \leq 1\} = 0$, but $f(x) > 0$ at every $x$. $f$ is integrable since given a positive integer $n$ and real number $\epsilon$ with $0 < \epsilon < \frac{1}{2}$, the partition $P_1 = \{0, 2^{-n} (1+\epsilon), 2^{-n+1} (1+\epsilon), \ldots, \frac{1}{2} (1+\epsilon), 1\}$ gives

$$ \begin{align*} L_{P_1}(f) &= 0 + \left[ \sum_{k=2}^n 2^{-k} \big( 2^{-k+1}(1+\epsilon)-2^{-k}(1+\epsilon) \big) \right] + \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}(1+\epsilon)\right) \\
L_{P_1}(f) &= (1+\epsilon) \sum_{k=2}^n 4^{-k} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{\epsilon}{4} = (1+\epsilon) \sum_{k=1}^n 4^{-k} + \frac{\epsilon}{4} \\
L_{P_1}(f) &= (1+\epsilon) \frac{1-4^{-n}}{3}
\end{align*} $$

And the partition $P_2 = \{0, 2^{-n}(1-\epsilon), 2^{-n+1}(1-\epsilon), \ldots, \frac{1}{2}(1-\epsilon), 1-\epsilon, 1\}$ gives

$$ \begin{align*} U_{P_2}(f) &= 1(2^{-n}(1-\epsilon)-0) + \left[\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-k} \big( 2^{-k+1}(1-\epsilon)-2^{-k}(1-\epsilon) \big)\right]  + (1-(1-\epsilon)) \\
U_{P_2}(f) &= 2^{-n} (1-\epsilon) + (1-\epsilon) \sum_{k=1}^n 4^{-k} + \epsilon \\
U_{P_2}(f) &= (1-\epsilon) \left(2^{-n} + \frac{1-4^{-n}}{3}\right) + \epsilon
\end{align*} $$

Since both bounds approach $\frac{1}{3}$ as $n \to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$, $f$ is integrable with

$$ \int_0^1 f(x)\, dx = \frac{1}{3} $$

But you don't really need $x'$, $x_1$, and $x_2$. Just say for any $x$ with $t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t$,

$$ f(x) \geq m_i' $$
$$ g(x) \geq m_i'' $$

by the definition of $\inf$. So

$$ f(x) + g(x) \geq m_i' + m_i'' $$

Since this is true for all $x$ in the interval,

$$ m_i = \inf\{f(x) + g(x) : t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i\} \geq m_i' + m_i'' $$